# Create empty rows/columns when save python pandas dataframe to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['one', 'three', 'two', 'one'], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'C': [-1, 8, 9, 11]})
```

I want the output in Excel spreadsheet to be
- row order sorted by column key, only output the first column key for each unique column key value, with extra empty row between different key values
- empty columns between column key and B

This is what I want to have in the output:

```
Key     B  C
One     1  -1
        4  11

Three   2  8

Two     3  9
```

What would be the most compact way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got your point.

But this is a little bit odd, why don't you firstly filter your collection to a correct one?

Suggest you are using `xlwt` module, first adjust your collection, then do `merge` to get your xls file correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import xlwt

df = {'key': ['one', 'three', 'two', 'one'], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'C': [-1, 8, 9, 11]}

# filter your collection, let the same key to be close for easy merging
df['key'].sort()
df['B'][1], df['B'][3] = df['B'][3], df['B'][1]
df['C'][1], df['C'][3] = df['C'][3], df['C'][1]

current_file = xlwt.Workbook()
table = current_file.add_sheet('sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)

table.write(0, 0, 'key')
for title_index, text in enumerate(df['key']):
    table.write(title_index+1, 0, text)


df.pop('key')
merging_list = []
for index, letter in enumerate(df.keys()):
    table.write(0, index+1, letter)
    nr = 1
    for content in df[letter]:
        table.write(nr, index+1, content)
        nr += 1

# you can merge more if you have multiple duplicate keys
# but do not foget to remember their indexes
table.merge(1, 2, 0, 0)


current_file.save('/tmp/test.xls')
```

then check your file `/tmp/test.xls`:

[image]